# Powershell script for replacing text of xml format multiple lines

Tags: xml, powershell

Here is the powershell script

```
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem . *.scd -rec
foreach ($file in $configFiles)
{
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    Foreach-Object { 
    $_ -replace '<Terminal .+\/>', '' `
       -replace '<Terminal [.|\n]*?<\/Terminal>', '' `
       -replace '<Private type=\"ABB.*?<\/Private>', '' `
       -replace '<ConnectivityNode.*?>.*?<\/ConnectivityNode>', '' `
       -replace '\r\n[\t\n\v\f\r ]+\r\n', '\r\n' 
    } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

The first replace is working just fine because the tag is single line but the rest are not working, nothing happens as they have other tags inside them as well. I wanted to know what's the correct Regular expression.

This is the group of tags that i want to replace(2nd replace) with ' ' what regular expression would work?

```
<Terminal name="T_grounded" connectivityNode="AA1/J1/Q01/grounded" 
    substationName="AA1" voltageLevelName="J1" bayName="Q01"
        cNodeName="grounded">
            <Private type="ABB SLD">
                <esld:Line>
                    <esld:Via x="244" y="116" />
                </esld:Line>
            </Private>
</Terminal>
```

In Notepad++ it's pretty simple as you can just mark . matches new line and replace all but i don't know how we will adapt it in powershell script.

Thanks in advance, please help me out.

Comment: Golden rule of programming written on stone tablets somewhere: don't use [Regex on X/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1422451)! Show us your original and desired output there are many DOM methods even XSLT to do what you need.

Comment: It's not up to me it's the task i have been given i'm going to scratch my face please help me out this time next time i will commit suicide before denying the golden rule lol.

Comment: Basically the output i want is the group of tags removed, that's why i'm replacing the tags with empty string.

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman back to the very first comment made on this question.

Comment: Again i can't use any other thing, this is the task now please anyone who can help?

Comment: I actually worked out how to do it for multiple lines and those regex work fine with everything(Notepad++ now don't need to mark . matches new line to make it work, online reg testers) it works with everything except powershell when run in powershell nothing happens can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the mode modifier, single line, you can treat your input as if it was all one line. This makes the `.` match newline characters and stuff too. Some something like this:

```
$test = @"
some junk
<Terminal name="T_grounded" connectivityNode="AA1/J1/Q01/grounded" 
    substationName="AA1" voltageLevelName="J1" bayName="Q01"
        cNodeName="grounded">
            <Private type="ABB SLD">
                <esld:Line>
                    <esld:Via x="244" y="116" />
                </esld:Line>
            </Private>
</Terminal> 
some more junk
"@

$test -replace "(?s)<Terminal.*Terminal>"," "
```

should rip out what you want.

mod modifier is added into the regex using `(?s)` and then you can just look for the start and end of the  node.

edit: in this case you'll also need to read your input in as raw data instead of line by line.

Comment: Solved it with this...
(?s)<Terminal .*?>(.|\s).*?</Terminal>