# How to debug why the replacing of multiline is not working in this PowerShell script?

Tags: c#, powershell

I wrote this code in PowerShell script but for some reason it's not working. The program itself is working but the replacing of multiline is not working - can anyone shed any light as to why?

```
Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | 
Out-Null

$OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$OpenFileDialog.filter = "SCD (*.scd)| *.scd"
$OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$OpenFileDialog.filename
}

$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\Users\Mr.Nephilim\Desktop\ABB"
#$inputdata = get-content $inputfile

#$configFiles = Read-Host 'Enter Complete directory to file'
(Get-Content $inputfile) |
Foreach-Object { 
$_ -replace  '(?ms)^\[\t\n\v\f\r ]<Private type="ABB.*?</Private>', ''
   #-replace '<Terminal .+\/>', '' `
   #-replace '<Terminal .*?>\s<\/Terminal>', '' `
   #-replace '<Private type=\"ABB(.|\n)*?<\/Private>', '' `
   #-replace '<ConnectivityNode.*?>(.|\n)*?<\/ConnectivityNode>', ''
   #-replace '<Terminal .+/>', '' `
   #-replace '<Private type="ABB.*?>.*?</Private>', '' `
   #-replace '<Terminal .+>', '' `
   #-replace '<Private type=\"ABB.*?>', '' `
   #-replace '<esld:.*?>', '' `
   #-replace '<esld:.*?\/>', '' `
   #-replace '</esld:.*?>', '' `
   #-replace '</Private.*?>', '' `
   #-replace '</Terminal.*>', '' `
   #-replace '<ConnectivityNode.*?>', '' `
   #-replace '</ConnectivityNode.*?>', '' 

} |

Set-Content $inputfile

(GC $inputfile)|?{$_.Trim(" `t")}|SC $inputfile
```

Comment: Maybe you're better off fixing the "replacing of multiline is not working" problem. What does "not working" mean? What do you mean by multiline?

Comment: `\[\t\n\v\f\r ]` -> `\s`, `.*?` -> `[\s\S]*?`?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911293/multiline-regex-in-powershell) can help you resolve the multiline issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45440774/powershell-script-for-replacing-text-of-xml-format-multiple-lines check this out doctorlove

Comment: Ansgar \s is not supported in powershell i think... any way i have tried the first 2 i'll see if [\s\S]*? works...

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do here? Open a dir, select a file and then what?

Comment: Open a file of a specific format using gui(from user), then load all its content, find the xml tags and replace them with empty string. To find a xml tag i'm using regex such as <Terminal.*?> etc tags which are self closing and are on a single line are easy to replace but tags which span over multiple lines are just not working. I run the regex written for multiple line on reg testers and they work just fine but when run on powershell they do nothing.

Comment: For example:
i want to replace 
<Terminal name="T_grounded" connectivityNode="AA1/J1/Q01/grounded" substationName="AA1" voltageLevelName="J1" bayName="Q01" cNodeName="grounded" /> with nothing i do ... -replace '<Terminal .*?/>', '' and it works but...
for multiple lines such as
<Private type="ABB SLD">
   <esld:Coord x="116" y="212" />
</Private>
i write <Private type="ABB.*?>\s<esld:.*?>\s</Private> and replace with ''
in theory and on online reg testers it works fine but in powershell it just do nothing.

Comment: @InnoBoY `"   " -match "\s"` definitely works by the way.

Comment: Converting this to another language is too broad for a Stack Overflow question, so I have modified it a bit, to ask for why the multiline issue does not work in the code that you have.

Comment: @InnoBoY I can assure you that `\s` works just fine in PowerShell (plus, you need the content of the file in a single string, as MatSnow pointed out). With that said, the comments to your previous question still stand. You'd get a much better result if you showed the desired output for your sample input.

Comment: ConnorLSW : Where would in the above code i'll put that line?
Angsar : the output i want is the to find a string and replace it with empty string basically find and delete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(?s)(.|\s).*? using this way it can be done...